# how to configure multiple interfaces with systemd-networkd

Tags: linux, networking, routing, systemd

I have three physical network interfaces one my machine, they are all connected to different subnets, the first interface is `eno1` with IP `10.10.24.157/24`, the second one is `eno2` with IP `10.10.25.160/25`, the third one is `enp8s0` with IP `10.10.26.160/25`. My current setup is like this:

eno1:

```
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
Address=10.10.24.157/24
DNS=8.8.8.8
Gateway=10.10.24.1
```

eno2:

```
[Match]
Name=eno2

[Network]
Address=10.10.25.160/25

[Route]
Gateway=10.10.25.129
Destination=224.0.0.0/4
Metric=400
```

enp8s0:

```
[Match]
Name=enp8s0

[Network]
Address=10.10.26.160/25
```

With this setup, I ping `eno1` and `eno2` from another subnet, but I cannot ping `enp8s0`, I tried to add Gateway to `enp8s0`, but there are some problems, if I add `10.10.26.129` as the Gateway of `enp8s0`, I cannot ping any of those interfaces(I guess the reason is that I cannot have multiple default gateways? But why could `eno2` have a gateway from its subnet?). If I add `10.10.24.1` as the Gateway of `enp8s0`, I still couldn't ping `enp8s0`(the address and the gateway must be in the same subnet?), how should I properly configure those three interfaces so that I can ping all of them from another subnet?

Comment: Which clients IP are the ICMP echo requests originated from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding a gateway to `enp8s0`:

```
[Match]
Name=enp8s0

[Network]
Address=10.10.26.160/25
Gateway=10.10.26.129
```